# Upload de arquivos e dados SERVLET

Tags: html5, java-ee, servlet

Como faço pra receber arquivos e outros parâmetros na Servlet? Segue o código de envio:

```
    <form action="myservlet" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="text" name="mytext">
      <input type="file" name="myfile">
      <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
```

ps: Vi exemplos de como pegar somente o "file" mas não sei como pegar o "file" e o "text" na servlet.

Answer (score 0):

Você pega os dados do inputText e file pelo name, usando o `request.getParameter("");` colocando entre as aspas com parenteses o name do input text Exemplo:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

String nome = request.getParameter("mytext");
 String file = request.getParameter("file");
}
```

Comment: Não dá certo, só vem o nome do arquivo na servlet, no caso arquivo.png

Comment: na sua pergunta você fala como pegar os dados do html ou jsp e colocar na servlet

Comment: quando vc clica no botão ele envia para a servlet especificada ?

Comment: Eu preciso tratar o arquivo na Servlet

Comment: no caso quero saber como eu pego o arquivo para mandar para o db ou mandar para uma pasta específica

Comment: poste o seu código da servlet e da classe responsavel por persistir os dados no banco de dados

Answer (score 0):

Solução do meu caso:

```
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    Map<String, String> fields = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, List<String>> multiValueFields = new HashMap<>();

    if (!ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {
        out.println("Nothing to upload");
        return;
    }
    FileItemFactory itemfactory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(itemfactory);
    try {

        List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);
        for (FileItem item : items) {

            if (!item.isFormField()) {
                String contentType = item.getContentType();
                if (!contentType.equals("image/png")) {
                    out.println("only png format image files supported");
                    continue;
                }
                File uploadDir = new File("C:\\");
                File file = File.createTempFile("img", ".png", uploadDir);

                item.write(file);

                fields.put("imagem", file.getPath());

                out.println("File Saved Successfully");
            } else {
                String name = item.getFieldName();
                String value = item.getString();

                if (!multiValueFields.containsKey(name)) {
                    multiValueFields.put(name, new ArrayList<String>());
                }

                fields.put(name, value);
                multiValueFields.get(name).add(value);
            }
        }

        String nome = fields.get("nome");
        String descricao = fields.get("descricao");
        String tipo = fields.get("tipo");

        String nomeImagem = fields.get("imagem");
        List<String> opcao = multiValueFields.get("opcao");

        Exercicio e = new Exercicio();
        e.setNome(nome);
        e.setTipo(tipo);
        e.setDescricao(descricao);
        Instrutor i = new Instrutor(request.getSession().getAttribute("usuario").toString());
        e.setInstrutor(i);
        e.setImagem(nomeImagem);
        ExercicioDAO dao = new ExercicioDAO();

        dao.cadastrar(e); //cadastra no db o obj exercicio

    } catch (FileUploadException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        out.println("upload fail");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        out.println("can't save");
    }
```